# List all rows with same values in a column - SQL

Tags: sql, list, duplicates

Hi i have a table as below with two column, 1.CODE, 2.Description

```
Code    Description 
DRU0001 ABCM 
DRU0002 ABCM 
DRU0003 ABCM 
DRU0004 ABCM 
DRU0005 ABVD 
DRU0006 ABVD 
DRU0007 ABVD 
DRU0008 ABVD 
DRU0009 AC 
DRU0010 AC 
DRU0011 ACE (1 day) 
DRU0012 ACE (1 day) 
DRU0013 ACE (1 day) 
DRU0014 ACE (3 day) IV 
DRU0015 ACE (3 day) IV 
DRU0016 ACE (3 day) IV 
DRU0017 ACE (3 day) IV
```

What I want IS A SQL CODE that will list me the all the rows which has the description 'ABCM'

```
select code, Description from Tables.Tables_OD8  WHERE Description ='ABCM'
```

But the above sql only displays one row and not all the 4 rows that has the description 'ABCM'

```
Code    Description 
DRU0001 ABCM 
DRU0002 ABCM 
DRU0003 ABCM 
DRU0004 ABCM
```

Any help much appriciated

thanks in advance

Comment: The SQL is correct, so the likely problem is that in your code you are executing the SQL but only reading the first row from the result set. Please post your code that executes the SQL and reads the row(s) if you want more help.

Comment: maybe there a re some spaces in your columns. Try `...WHERE Description like 'ABCM%'`

Comment: Is it possible that your query tool is limiting the results to a single row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is correct for the task that you are trying to perform, so the likely culprit is your data: other descriptions probably contain trailing blanks.

To verify, run this query:

```
select code, '"'+Description+'"' from Tables.Tables_OD8
```

This assumes an RDBMS with `+` used for concatenation; some DBs use `||` instead of a `+`

```
select code, '"'||Description||'"' from Tables.Tables_OD8
```

To work around this, use

```
select code, Description from Tables.Tables_OD8  WHERE Description LIKE 'ABCM%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code FROM table WHERE description LIKE '%ABCM%'
```

Is this what you asked?